# Transform weka classify result to Drools

Tags: drools, weka

I'm using weka to train my insurance data to get the classify rules, I choose Jrip and J48(C4.5 decision tree) by using weka java api and get rule like`(age > 18) => class=1`. Is there any way that I can get weka result and transfrom it into LHS(left-hand-side) of drools rule expression?

Answer (score 0):

For J48 there are 3 ways to output generated tree. In each version you need to parse the output and construct your expressions.

```
J48 cls = new J48();
...
cls.buildClassifier(instances);
```

1. `cls.toString()` returns build tree as string. You need to parse between "J48 pruned tree" and "Number of Leaves"
2. `cls.toSource(className)` Returns tree as an [if-then](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html#toSource-java.lang.String-) statement.
3. `cls.graph()` returns build tree in [dotty format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language))